# Solution for calling multiple python scripts in real time from a nodejs server

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, raspberry-pi, hardware

Well this is a bit more complex problem, I try to explain it widely enough so that you can understand what we need.

The project is about some stepper motors, which are controlled by a raspi, which runs a nodejs server, which serves the webapp. The Webapp communicates via websocket with the nodejs server.

You can control the direction and speed with a joystick in the webapp, everytime the values change, the webapp emits a message with the websocket prototcol to the server.

When the nodejs server gets these messages, it starts a subprocess, like this:

```
     child_process.exec('python /home/pi/Adafruit-Motor-HAT-Python-Library/examples/StartStepper.py 10 1 10 0', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("child processes failed with error code: " +
                err.code);
        }
        console.log(stdout);
    });
```

I setup the script for the stepper so, that I can set the steps, rpm and stepstyles as arguments for the script.

So this all works fine, I can start the script with my events and so on.

BUT if I move the joystick, the script gets called multiple times, which is kinda ok, because it has to be called if I switch from left to the right or if I change the speed, but the scripts are like on a stack and dont stop when a new one starts, they just do their job and run until they are done. I'd like them to stop as soon as the script gets called again, but I'm not that deep into python. Maybe it would even work, to change the attributes of the thread, which controls the steppers in runtime? I'm not sure about that. I just want to control my steppers in real time, which has sadly to be done with python, because the stepper controller, has no support for other languages.

Update:
So I try to kill the process now before I execute a new one:

```
var child_process = require('child_process');

child_process.kill(); //Default killSignal
    child_process.exec('python /home/pi/Adafruit-Motor-HAT-Python-Library/examples/StartStepperL.py 10 1 10 0', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("child processes failed with error code: " +
                err.code);
        }
        console.log(stdout);
    });
```

This obviously doesn't work, because I don't handle the killSignal, but I don't get where to handle it, I already read the documentation about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just keep a reference to the child process at all times, and before spawning a new one, if an old one exists kill it. This way you handle it all from the node.js app.

Check out child process kill:
https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_kill_signal

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that out, the hardware communication is completely new to me, so much of the obvious things aren't that obvious for me :) Thanks for the hint.

Comment: I updated my question, because I need some help to kill the process, I hope you can help me.